# @InjectMock on entity manager results in `WrongTypeOfReturnValue` exception during test execution

Tags: quarkus

Keep on getting WrongTypeOfReturnValue for `TypedQuery`.. aparenty `Query` is expected on mocking injected `EntityManager`

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
TypedQuery$MockitoMock$1029119198 cannot be returned by createNamedQuery()
createNamedQuery() should return Query
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

```java
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource( WireMockLCM.class )
public class BroEventGeneratorTest {

    // CHECKSTYLE:OFF
    @WireMockLCM.InjectWireMock
    WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    @InjectMock
    EntityManager entityManager;

// ....


    @Test
    public void testCreateActiveSubscription() {
        // -- prepare
        TypedQuery<TransactionEventEntity> trxQuery = mock( TypedQuery.class );
        //doReturn( trxQuery ).when( entityManager ).createNamedQuery( eq( "selectTransactionsFrom" ), eq( TransactionEventEntity.class ) );
        when( entityManager.createNamedQuery( eq( "selectTransactionsFrom" ), eq( TransactionEventEntity.class ) ) ).thenReturn( trxQuery ); // <-------- on this line
        TransactionEventEntity transactionEventEntity = new TransactionEventEntity();
```

method:

```java
    @Scheduled( every = "60s", concurrentExecution = SKIP )
    @Transactional
    public void scan() {
        LOG.info( "scanning transaction: started" );
        TypedQuery<TransactionEventEntity> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery( "selectTransactionsFrom", TransactionEventEntity.class );
```

I'm still looking for a good way to control triggering the `scan` method, for it not immediately go off. However, omitting the `@Scheduled` application does not fix the issue.

Testcase works when I run the test a simple unit test.. but, i want to test the integration with Quarkus.

Comment: I really don't think that mocking the `EntityManager` is the right way to go...

Comment: I don't want to run full scaled integration test dragging in oracle specifics. So, controlling the entity manager is the thing I'm left with. What are you suggesting?

Comment: Do you not use a repository pattern or something like that? That would be a better target for mocking

Comment: I have several problems.. Migrating large jboss applications. So refactoring UT is not always an option. In this particular case I'm now using rider-cdi  which is a nice tool and for my current problem suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. The only solution I found so far, is to use the hibernate Query class directly.

```
import org.hibernate.query.Query;

@InjectMock
EntityManager entityManager;

// ...

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Query<TransactionEventEntity> trxQuery = mock(Query.class); // Hibernate-Query instead of TypedQuery
when(entityManager.createNamedQuery(eq("selectTransactionsFrom"), eq(TransactionEventEntity.class))).thenReturn(trxQuery);
```

If you have found a better solution yourself, please let me know.